# Mysql cursor not returning anything in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

I am trying to use a cursor in my stored procedure in MySQL Workbench.
The code looks like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS order_procedure$$
CREATE PROCEDURE order_procedure()
BEGIN

DECLARE id INT;
DECLARE flag INT DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE ordercursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT id FROM wp_posts
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'shop_order';

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET flag = 1;

OPEN ordercursor;

get_orders:LOOP
FETCH NEXT FROM ordercursor INTO id;
IF flag = 1 THEN 
    LEAVE get_orders;
END IF;

SELECT * FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items oi
INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta oim ON oim.order_item_id = oi.order_item_id
WHERE oi.order_id = id;

END LOOP;
CLOSE ordercursor; 
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

If I try:

```
SELECT id FROM wp_posts
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'shop_order';
```

I get the results I want, ie. 15 rows with `order_ids`, but when I `CALL order_procedure();` I get nothing.

When I tried printing the ID's I get `NULL`.
What did I miss?

Edit: Added screenshot showing the `SELECT` the cursor uses.
[image: mysql]

Comment: When you run this query in a gui:  `SELECT id FROM wp_posts
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'shop_order';`, does it give any results ? Could be that there are no rows returned bt the cursor.

Comment: Hey, yes I get my wanted ID's. I'll add a screenshot.

Comment: Is there a column named `id` in one of the joined table ? If yes, then this condition: `WHERE oi.order_id = id;` does not refer to variable `id`, but to the column `id`. In this case use different variable name, for example `v_id`.

Comment: @kordirko I think you might have solved it! However, there is NO column named `id` in any of the tables, but it worked when I changed the name to `v_id`Write it in an answer and I will mark it as solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the suggestion in the comment section turned out to be the answer, EVEN THOUGH there is no column named `id` in any of the joined tables, I guess I will have to answer the question if anybody else has the same problem.

So, the answer is to not name the variable `id` but something like `v_id` or what ever comes to your mind really.
:)

Answer (score 0):

First create a table "mytable" as per required columns whatever you want from this procedure then change field name in below procedure and check.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS order_procedure$$
CREATE PROCEDURE order_procedure()
BEGIN

DECLARE _id INT;
DECLARE flag INT DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE ordercursor CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM wp_posts WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'shop_order';

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET flag = 1;

OPEN ordercursor;
BEGIN
REPEAT
FETCH ordercursor INTO _id;
IF _id = '' THEN
    SET flag = 1;
END IF; 

        IF (flag<>1) THEN
    SET @str1=CONCAT("insert into mytable SELECT oi.field1,oi.field2,oim.field1 FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items oi INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta oim ON oim.order_item_id = oi.order_item_id WHERE oi.order_id ='",_id,"'");
            PREPARE stmt1 FROM @str1;
            EXECUTE stmt1;
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

               END IF;
UNTIL flag
END REPEAT;
END;
CLOSE ordercursor; 
SELECT * FROM mytable;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Sorry, not was I was looking for. Thanks for the answer though.